# They have been vs. they will have been

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

What are the different meaning int the following sentences?

1. They **have been dating** for a year now.
2. They **will have been dating** for a year now.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the difference between discussing two people who started dating 11 months ago, (let's call them Couple I) vs people who started dating 12 months ago (Couple II).

Couple I will have been dating for a year now once another month passes by (this tense is known as [Future Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect)).

Couple II has been dating for a year now (this is known as [Present Perfect Continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html)).